# Mathematical Derivation of Expression for the Total Power Received By Earth from Sun, via Integration

Tags: integration, power, planets, geometry, intensity

I recently tried to derive an expression for the total power received by the earth from the sun, using integration. However, I am stuck at an integration step. Would appreciate if anyone could help with this.

Consider the Earth located at a distance of Ro from the sun. Consider the sun as a point source of power, emitting power of $P_0$.

Intensity at every point on the surface of the earth is not the same, as each point on the earth is located at a different distance from the sun. Only concentric rings are located the same distance from the sun, and thus will capture the same intensity.

**Intensity expression:**

Let the radius of a concentric ring be $R$. Let the depth of the concentric ring from the surface of earth be $x$.

Intensity, $$I = \frac{P_0}{4\pi[(R_0 + x)^2 + R^2)]} \tag{1}$$

Finding an expression for $x$ in terms of $R$:

$$R_e^2 = R^2 + (R_e - x)^2,$$ where $R_e$ is the radius of the Earth

$$x = R_e - \sqrt {R_e^2 - R^2} \tag{2}$$

Subst (2) into (1): $$I = \frac{P_0}{4\pi[(R_0 + R_e - \sqrt {R_e^2 - R^2})^2 + R^2]} \tag{3}$$

**Area expression:**

Next, I find an expression for area of an infinitesimally thin concentric ring, $dA$. I can slice the concentric ring once, to make it into a rectangle.

Thus, area of concentric ring, $$dA = 2\pi R\ dR \tag{4}$$

**Power collected integration expression:**

$$\begin{align}
&\text{Power collected on earth} \\
&= \int I\ dA \\
&= \int_0^{R_e} \frac{P_0}{4\pi[(R_0 + R_e - \sqrt {R_e^2 - R^2})^2 + R^2]} 2\pi R\ dR \\
&= \frac{P_0}{2} \int_0^{R_e} \frac{R}{ 2R^2 - 2(R_0+R_e)\sqrt{R_e^2 - R^2} + R_e^2 + (R_0 + R_e)^2}\ dR
\end{align}$$

I am now stuck, don't know how to integrate this further. The variable is $R$. Appreciate any insights or ways to proceed. Please help.

Comment: I tried using online calculators to solve the integral. But even they could not. I am not sure why - it seems like a pretty basic problem, and I'm sure there must be a solution to this. Please help.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am not very familiar with this, and I have some limits on my humble PC, hence not able to do so. Could I request for you to help me do the formatting needed? Would truly, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I did the [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)
for you to get you starting. Please review for any mistakes I might have introduced.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect.

Comment: If you can program with an available language, it is not difficult to set up a numeric integration. (Use the middle or average  value of the function in each increment).

Comment: Substitute $R^2=x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substitute

$$R^2=x\quad ,2\,R\,dR=dx\quad,dR=\frac{1}{2\,R}\,dx$$

your integral

$$\int_0^{R_e} (...)\,dR\mapsto\\ \frac{P_0}{4} \int_0^{R_e^2}\frac{1}{(x-x_1)\,(x-x_2)}\,dx=\frac{P_0}{4}\,\frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)}\left[\ln(x-x_1)-\ln(x-x_2)\right]\bigg|_0^{R_e^2}$$

where  $~x_1~,x_2$ are  the solution of this quadratic equation:

$$f(x)=4\,{x}^{2}+ \left( 4\,{{c_2}}^{2}+4\,{c_1} \right) x+{{ c_1}}^
{2}-4\,{{c_2}}^{2}{{ R_e}}^{2}
=0\\
c_1=R_e^2+(R_0+R_e)^2\\
c_2=(R_e+R_0)
$$

Answer (score 2):

I know you are trying to solve the problem by integrating.
But you can avoid the bothersome integration altogether by using
the concept of [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle).

[image: solid angle]
<sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Solid angle](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Solid_Angle.png))</sub>

Viewed from the sun, the earth spans a solid angle $\Omega$.
And the whole sphere around the sun has the solid angle $4\pi$.
Thus the power $P$ received by the earth is the fraction of the total
power $P_0$ emitted into the solid angle $\Omega$:
$$P=\frac{P_0\Omega}{4\pi} \tag{1}$$

So the remaining work is to calculate $\Omega$.

Viewed from the sun, the earth appears with an half angle $\theta$.
[image]
From the right triangle we see
$$\sin\theta=\frac{R_e}{R_0} \tag{2}$$

The solid angle of a circular cone (with half angle $\theta$)
is known to be $\Omega=2\pi(1-\cos\theta)$
(see [Wikipedia - Solid angle - Solid angles for common objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Solid_angles_for_common_objects)).
So with using (2) we get
$$\Omega=2\pi(1-\cos\theta)
=2\pi\left(1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}\right)
=2\pi\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{R_e^2}{R_0^2}}\right)
\tag{3}$$

Using (1) and (3) we finally get the power
$$P=\frac{P_0\Omega}{4\pi}
=\frac{P_0}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{R_e^2}{R_0^2}}\right).$$

For $R_e \ll R_0$ this can be approximated by
$$P\approx \frac{P_0R_e^2}{4R_0^2}.$$